# Why does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n\psi$ converge in norm for $\{P_n\}_n$ a sequence of orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space $H$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $\{P_n\}_n$ be a countably infinite collection of unique orthogonal projections in a Hilbert space $H$ and $\psi\in H\setminus \{0\}$. Then why does the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n\psi$ converge in norm? It is certainly the case that $||\psi||^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty ||P_n\psi||^2 < \infty$ as per the Pythagorean Theorem, but I don't see why this would show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ||P_n\psi|| < \infty$.

I sort of understand the motivation for the claim: If $n_1,n_2,\dots$ are such indices that $P_{n_k}\psi\neq 0$, then $\psi = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P_{n_k}\psi$ and as each $P_{n_k}$ is an orthogonal projection we have that $\psi = P_{n_1}\psi + P_{n_1}^\perp\psi, P_{n_1}^\perp\psi = \sum_{k=2}^\infty P_{n_k}\psi$ etc. That is, the "mass" of $\psi$ is spread out on different orthogonal parts of the space $H$ and there is a finite total sum of the mass. As each different component is orthogonal to each other, some component $P_{n_k}\psi$ cannot affect $P_{n_l}\psi$ for $k\neq l$. But this does not constitute to a proper proof.

Comment: Why would you need to show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\|P_n\| < \infty$? This should not be true but it also is not what you want to show.

Comment: The assertion that $\sum_n \|P_n\| < \infty$ is false because $\|P_n\| = 1$ unless $P_n=0$ since $P_n$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: @podiki So sorry! I forgot $\psi$ from the norm.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ||P_n\psi|| < \infty$ is generally not true either. The convergence in norm of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n\psi$ does not mean that. It means that for some $\varphi\in H,$ $\lim_n\|(\sum_{k\le n}P_k\psi)-\varphi\|=0.$

Comment: You need another assumption such as $P_n P_m = 0$ when $n\not = m$.

Comment: @Gribouillis i.) Isn't that given by the orthogonality of the projections? ii.) How does this help us?

Comment: «Orthogonal projection» means self-adjoint projection, so it needs to be clarified.

Comment: @CartesianBear what if $P_n$ was the same for every $n$? Here's a hint: use $\left\| \sum_{n=k}^m P_n\psi\right\|= \sqrt{ \sum_{n=k}^m || P_n\psi||^2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of orthogonal projection operators in a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582320/sum-of-orthogonal-projection-operators-in-a-hilbert-space) See also [Countable sum of orthogonal projections with orthogonal ranges; uniformly bounded monotone sequence of self-adjoint operators is strongly convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626046).

Comment: @AnneBauval This does answer my question. Thanks!